# How to use Geokit on a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geokit

I am using Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.2.0. I want to use geokit to convert an address to latitude and longitude. I already did gem install geokit in my terminal. I also included gem 'geokit' in my Gemfile, and run bundle install.

On a controller, I try to use the function Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode().

When I just use it like this, I got this error : uninitialized constant AnswersController::Geocoders (my controller is called Answers)

When I try to add require 'geokit' at the beginning of the controller, I got the error : cannot load such file --geokit.

Do you have any idea of what I could do to solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance

Here is my controller

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'geokit'
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def render_page2
  render('page2')
end
def answer_page2
if params[:address_origin] && params[:address_destination]
  session[:lat_origin] = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(params[:address_origin]).lat
  session[:lon_origin] = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(params[:address_origin]).lng
  session[:lat_destination] = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(params[:address_destination]).lat
  session[:lon_destination] = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(params[:address_destination]).lng
  #session[:lat_origin] = 37.793688
  #session[:lon_origin] = -122.3958692
  #session[:lat_destination] = 37.866437
  #session[:lon_destination] = -122.265415
  redirect_to '/page3'
else
  flash[:message] = "All the questions are required on this page."
  redirect_to '/page2'
end
end
end
```

Comment: Show us your code in `answers_controller.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. The code is good and all the steps posted by Prakash are good.

But I needed to restart the rails server on the terminal after you run those steps, that is why it was not working on the browser ! Now it is working.

Thanks everyone for your answers. I don't know if it is the best solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

> I already did gem install geokit in my terminal. I also included gem
>   'geokit' in my Gemfile, and run bundle install.

No need for doing both.

Follow these steps to make sure you have installed the `geokit` gem correctly:

a. Add `geokit` gem in the Gemfile

```
# Gemfile
gem 'geokit'
```

b. Run `bundle install`; verify the gem is installed with `bundle show geokit`.

c. Try the following in the rails console:

```
$ rails console
> a=Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode '140 Market St, San Francisco, CA'
 => #<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x007fe877305c70 @all=[#<Geokit::GeoLoc:0x007fe877305c70 ...>], @street_address="140 Market Street", @sub_premise=nil, @street_number="140", @street_name="Market Street", @city="San Francisco", @state=nil, @state_code="CA", @state_name="California", @zip="94105", @country_code="US", @province="CA", @success=true, @precision="address", @full_address="140 Market Street, San Francisco, CA 94105, USA", @lat=37.793688, @lng=-122.3958692, @provider="google", @neighborhood="Financial District", @district="San Francisco County", @country="United States", @accuracy=8, @suggested_bounds=#<Geokit::Bounds:0x007fe8772fef60 @sw=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x007fe8772fef88 @lat=37.7923338697085, @lng=-122.3972116302915>, @ne=#<Geokit::LatLng:0x007fe8772ff050 @lat=37.7950318302915, @lng=-122.3945136697085>>> 
> a.ll
 => "37.793688,-122.3958692"
```

Comment: I just don't know how to use it inside my project. I got those errors when I run rails server and I launch my app on a browser using localhost